# Display array info in text box and button in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

How can I display the info in the first line of my stories array in the storyLabel text, choice1Button and choice2Button when I run the app?

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var storyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var choice1Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choice2Button: UIButton!
    
    let stories = [

        Story(title: "You see a fork in the road", choice1: "Take a left", choice2: "Take a right"),
        Story(title: "You see a tiger", choice1: "Shout for help", choice2: "Play dead"),
        Story(title: "You find a treasure chest", choice1: "Open it", choice2: "Check for traps")
    ]
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        updateUI()

        
    }
    
    @objc func updateUI() {
        storyLabel.text = [1][0]
        choice1Button.setTitle(choice1, for: .normal)
        choice2Button.setTitle(Story[2], for: .normal)
    }
    
    @IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on this I have managed to solve it;

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var storyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var choice1Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choice2Button: UIButton!

var storyNumber = 0

let stories = [

    Story(title: "You see a fork in the road", choice1: "Take a left", choice2: "Take a right"),
    Story(title: "You see a tiger", choice1: "Shout for help", choice2: "Play dead"),
    Story(title: "You find a treasure chest", choice1: "Open it", choice2: "Check for traps")
]

func getStoryTitle() -> String {
    return stories[storyNumber].title
}

func getChoice1() -> String{
    return stories[storyNumber].choice1
}

func getChoice2() -> String {
    return stories[storyNumber].choice2
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    updateUI()

    
}

func updateUI() {
    storyLabel.text = getStoryTitle()
    choice1Button.setTitle(getChoice1(), for: .normal)
    choice2Button.setTitle(getChoice2(), for: .normal)
}

@IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

}